# Squid or Polipo

Tags: proxy, squid

Currently I am using Squid3 on my netbook, which has an Atom N450 processor and 1 GB of RAM running ubuntu. The proxy is used to share the internet connection with a small group of PC's (3 machines) over ad-hoc wi-fi. Another reason for using squid cache is to bring down data usage, as my internet connection come with a usage limit of 2 Gbits per month. I found that squid3 is little heavier for my netbook, as the processor fan will be always active whenever squid is being used. I have plans to go for Polipo, as it is lighweight, and better performance results according to [this test](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo//bench.html). But in the documentation for Polipo, there is no information about HTTPS support, and I always access sites which use HTTPS on my LAN Pc's. So, would Polipo be a better solution for my requirements? Efficient data caching is my first priority, and cached data shouldn't get deleted during reboots.

Comment: Then IMO squid is the best choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance differences between both for such a small setup are probably not noticeable.

However, traffic over HTTPS is NOT cached by squid3 anyway, as far as I know. So if you use the proxy to save bandwidth, all HTTPS traffic will not be cached, so you are not saving anything.

In any case, Polipo is more lightweight, so give it a go. It's also much easier to configure.

Squid is much more powerful, and more oriented to "enterprise" environments. I manage a Squid server for the school where I work, and Polipo just isn't an option.

Comment: Yes, HTTPS is not cacheable. There is an option, but it breaks the security and the browsers complain about it.